# ¿Cómo hago para poder mostrar en un HTML la información almacenada en el Storage usando @ionic/storage?

Tags: angular, ionic, angular7

Estoy haciendo un prototipo de red social usando Ionic 4, y estoy actualmente construyendo la página que contiene la información del usuario (nombre del usuario, nombre de usuario, etc.). Estoy almacenando los datos que me retorna la parte del login en el Storage haciendo uso de @ionic/storage, entonces lo que quiero hacer es simplemente mostrar en el html de la página donde se supone se debe mostrar la información del usuario la información que está almacenada en el IonicStorage.

Aquí está el servicio que se encarga de la parte del login y que almacena los datos que retorna el mismo en el Ionic Storage

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class UsersService {

  private url = environment.url;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private storage: Storage) { }



  register(name: string, username: string, email: string, password: string) {

    const body = new HttpParams()
    .set('name', name)
    .set('username', username)
    .set('email', email)
    .set('password', password)
    .set('provider', 'local');

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      })
    };
    this.http.post<any>(`${this.url}/signup`, body.toString(), httpOptions).subscribe((data) => {console.log(data);});
  }

  login(email: string, password: string) {
    const body = new HttpParams()
    .set('email', email)
    .set('password', password);
    const HttpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      })
    };
    this.http.post<any>(`${this.url}/login`, body.toString(), HttpOptions).subscribe((data) => {this.storage.set('userData', data); console.log(data)}, (error) => {console.log(error)});
  }
}
```

Y aquí está el typescript de la página en la que quiero mostrar

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UsersService } from '../../services/users.service';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab2',
  templateUrl: './tab2.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tab2.page.scss'],
})
export class Tab2Page implements OnInit {

  name: string;
  username: string;

  constructor(private storage: Storage) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ionViewWillEnter() {
    this.getUserData();
  }

  getUserData() {
   this.storage.get('userData');
  }

}
```

Y aquí el HTML de la página

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color='primary'>
      <ion-buttons>
        <ion-button slot='end' href=''>
          <ion-icon name='log-out'></ion-icon>
        </ion-button>
        <ion-title>Profile</ion-title>
      </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar>
        <img src='http://www.personalbrandingblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/blank-profile-picture-973460_640.png'>
        <ion-label>Profile Picture</ion-label>
      </ion-avatar>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Name: {{}}</ion-label>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Username: {{}}</ion-label>
  </ion-item>

</ion-content>
```

Comment: ¿Dónde tienes el problema?. No he trabajado con Ionic Storage, pero supongo que en la función getUserData() recuperas dicha información.